# Escaping special characters when naming a table column without setting define off

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Before I posted my question, I read up various posts on this site about how to escape a special character when inserting a new field value or looking for a field name in the where clause. What I did not find was how to escape a special character when you want to name a table or column with one.

So, I want to name fieldA as `this&that`, e.g.

```
select fieldA this&that from tableA
```

I also want to use a substitution variable (`&var`) in the same query, so `set define off` wouldn't help.

I tried to use `'this' || chr(38) || 'that'` with or without single quotes, but SQL Developer doesn't like either.

Any ideas?

Comment: this&that is just an example. The name I want to use is a different one that does have an ampersand in it.

Comment: Actually *naming* a table or column, as an object identifier in the data dictionary; or using a column (or less likely table) alias in a standalone query?

Comment: Apologies, I was mainly talking about alias. The last bit of your comment actually resolved my issue (set define "^"
select fieldA "this&that" from tableA where fieldB = ^var;).
Thanks for the detailed post and your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to quote the identifier, but this is a really bad idea; every reference to the column everywhere will also have to be quoted and match the case exactly. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13798035/266304), and [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129), which advises against using quoted identifiers.

It's an even worse idea with an ampersand because of its use for substitution variables, as you're seeing. To create the table and then use substitution variables in the same script you would need to turn off defines before the creation, and then turn them back on afterwards:

```
set define off
create table bad_idea("this&that" number);
set define on
```

But you still couldn't refer to the table name and a substitution variable in the same statement, unless you set `define` to something non-standard:

```
set define "^"
insert into bad_idea("this&that") values (^var);
```

But again everything that ever refers to that column will need to take that into account too, as well as the case and quoting.

I'd seriously reconsider and make it something like `this_and_that`, or omit the 'and' part completely if it isn't really adding anything (or your real column name is approaching the length limit).

If you only need it as a column alias you can do the same thing, and it would be slightly less painful, but still not ideal:

```
set define "^"
select fieldA "this&that" from tableA where fieldB = ^var;
```