# dropping a schema with a badly chosen name in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How to drop a schema which has a an additional space in its name? When listing out the schemas it shows up as `BABBLER GROUP`. But when trying to drop (`sys as sysdba`) using `drop user BABBLER GROUP CASCADE;` it shows error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quotes; e.g. `drop user "BABBLER GROUP" CASCADE`

The same is true for any object with a space in its name.

NB: Per commments here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13798120/361842
Some tools aren't compatible with this feature; `SQL Plus` should be.

Oracle documentation on the same here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm