# Is it possible to have a % symbol in my column name?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to add a new column to an existing table, but when I try to create this column name I'm getting an invalid character error.

SQL Error: ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.

This is my code:

Alter Table Calculations
Add WEIGHTED_% Number;

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Double quotes escape: `Add "WEIGHTED_%"` - but its quite annoying to have to subsequently - in every single query that addresses this field -  escape it again, whats wrong with `WEIGHTED_PERCENT`?

Comment: [See the database object naming rules.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm) Particularly number 7. Also note that Oracle does not recommend using quoted identifiers, which you would have to do here.

Comment: Also [possibly a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13798035/266304); I can't see a question specifically about using a %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't recommend using the % symbol in you name I would recommend typing Percent instead. But as the error says you must en-capsule you column name in double quotes.

```
Alter Table Calculations Add "WEIGHTED_%" Number;
```

Not sure then it would still work because % is a reserved character for Doing like query and including them in exposed query is considered a vulnerability because it allows SQL injection.

Comment: Using the `%` character (within double quotes) in a `SELECT` query does **not** introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities. If the scripting language you are using to call the SQL commands uses `%` as a special character then that may be a separate issue but that is nothing to do with the SQL and is entirely language dependent on how you are calling the SQL commands.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Possible. Use double code for column name. Check the attached screen shot. 
[image]

But it's not good to use % in the column name. Not recommended.