# Tableau Oracle DB SQL column name select with spaces

Tags: sql, oracle, tableau-api

I am using custom SQL query in Tableau which is connected to a table in an Oracle DB. I have some column names with spaces and some without spaces. I get an error if I use a column name with space. Please see below:

```
Column Names
"Department"
"Job Type"
```

**Methods used for column name WITHOUT space**

```
SELECT Department FROM OG_COCKPIT_HC_CONTR_V -- (WORKS!)

SELECT (Department) FROM OG_COCKPIT_HC_CONTR_V -- (WORKS!)

SELECT "Department" FROM OG_COCKPIT_HC_CONTR_V -- (DOESN'T WORK)

SELECT [Department] FROM OG_COCKPIT_HC_CONTR_V -- (DOESN'T WORK)

SELECT 'Department' FROM OG_COCKPIT_HC_CONTR_V -- (DOESN'T WORK)
```

For the "Job Type" field none of the above works. Do you know what is the right syntax?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798035/oracle-table-column-name-with-space the double quotes should work. Did you check to make sure it's not case sensitive and that you're typing it exactly the same?

Comment: Single quotes are for sting constants not for identifiers. And square brackets are invalid in SQL identifiers. `(Department)`  is **exactly** the same as `Department`. But `Department` and `"Department"` are two different columns names: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT "Department","Job Type" FROM OG_COCKPIT_HC_CONTR_V
```

should work fine, but keep in mind is case sensitive.

Ted.

Comment: It probably won't work. Department and "Department" are not the same column names.

Answer (score 2):

If `SELECT Department ...` works but `SELECT "Department" ...` doesn't work, then it means that column Department was defined without double quotes and is case insensitive. All following statements should work fine:

```
select Department, "Job Type" FROM og_cockpit_hc_contr_v;
select department, "Job Type" FROM og_cockpit_hc_contr_v;
select DEPARTMENT, "Job Type" FROM og_cockpit_hc_contr_v;
```

Probably a typo in Job Type? Consider an example below:

```
SQL>     create or replace view og_cockpit_hc_contr_v as 
         select 'Dep1' as Department, 'Dummy' as "Job Type" from dual
         ;

SQL>     select column_name from user_tab_cols 
         where table_name= 'OG_COCKPIT_HC_CONTR_V'
         and (upper(column_name) like 'JOB%' or upper(column_name) like'DEP%')
         ;

COLUMN_NAME
-----------------
DEPARTMENT
Job Type

SQL>     col department for a10
SQL>     col "Job Type" for a10
SQL>     select Department, "Job Type" FROM og_cockpit_hc_contr_v;

DEPARTMENT Job Type
---------- ----------
Dep1       Dummy
```

[Note:](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223)
Oracle does not recommend using quoted identifiers for database object names. These quoted identifiers are accepted by SQL*Plus, but they may not be valid when using other tools that manage database objects.