# ORACLE/SQL: Wildcard literally in a column name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in which a column name begins with a wildcard. So one of the column is named `_Test_`

How can I access this column?

```
select _TEST_ from Table
```

throws an error, as well as

```
select * 
from Table 
where _TEST_ = 123
```

I tried suggestions with "escape", using `[_TEST_]`, or `\_TEST\_` but nothing worked. I cannot change the table.

EDIT (Thanks to @Alex Poole) : `select * from Table Where "_TEST_"=123` works. But `select "_TEST_" from Table` does not.

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM "_TEST_"` work?

Comment: See the answer here on double-quotes in queries to oracle dbs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13798120/4636715

Comment: @SalmanA `Select "_TEST_" from Table` does not work.

Comment: It isn't a wildcard in that context, so escaping isn't relevant (both apply to `like`); but the [rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html) mean it must be a quoted identifier. You have to match the case exactly too - so `select * from Table Where "_Test_"=123`, based on what you said the column is actually called. (This is why you should avoid using quoted identifiers...)

Comment: `select "\_Test\_" from table`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An underscore is only a wildcard for the `like` [pattern-matching condition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html). In the context you are trying to use it, it is not a wildcard. The column name just contains an underscore.

The documenation on [Database Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html) shows the rules for object names, including rule 6:

> Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any character.

As your column name starts with an underscore, the column must have been defined with a quoted identifier when the table was created, e.g.:

```
create table your_table (test number, "_Test_" number);
```

You can see the exact name for each column in the data dictionary:

```
COLUMN_NAME                   
------------------------------
TEST
_Test_
```

If a column (or any object) follows the non-quoted-identifier rules then it is recorded in uppercase in the data dictionary, but you can refer to it without quotes and with any case; so any of these are valid:

```
select * from your_table where TEST = 123;
select * from your_table where Test = 123;
select * from your_table where test = 123;
select * from your_table where tEsT = 123;
```

But if for a quoted identifier you always have to uses quotes and exactly the same case when referring to it. So these error:

```
select * from your_table where _TEST_ = 123;
select * from your_table where _Test_ = 123;
select * from your_table where "_TEST_" = 123;
```

(the first two with `ORA-00911: invalid character`, the third with `ORA-00904: "_TEST_": invalid identifier` because of the case difference). You have to match exactly, so only this is valid:

```
select * from your_table where "_Test_" = 123;
```

This is why quoted identifiers are a pain to work with and should be avoided if possible. Oracle even advise against using them.